# iPhone will only focus on one html input text of two on screen?

Tags: html, ios, reactjs, input, sass

So I have two input text boxes in a React app. I can enter input into one, but then it refuses to focus on the other. If I focus outside of the text box and click the other one, it refocuses on the first text box. If I reload the page and input into the second text box first, then it refuses to focus on the first text box.

I have tried the "-webkit-user-select: text;" approach I found in similar help questions, but to no avail. The issue only occurs on iOS devices.

Here's my SCSS -

```
.formField {
input {

border: 1px solid var(--line-color);
width: 380px;
height: 45px;
background-color: var(--background-color1);
padding: 10px;
font-size: 19px;
font-family: var(--font-family-semibold);
color: var(--text-color);
box-sizing: border-box;
&::placeholder {
  font-size: 19px;
  color: var(--placeholder-color);
  font-family: var(--font-family-semibold);
}
&:focus {
  padding: 9px;
  outline: var(--onfocus-outline);
  border: var(--onfocus-border);
  border-radius: var(--onfocus-border-radius);
}

@include for-phone-portrait {
  width: 310px;
  height: 40px;
}}}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

[How it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZODpV.jpg)
[Better looking one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VKoz.png)

Comment: Actually had nothing to do with the SCSS. We were using the following method to set the correct position for character with the currency mask, and it was firing on both onChange and onBlur. Preventing it from firing onBlur removed this issue.
  if (!isBlur) setTimeout(() => {
    inputElement.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
  }, 0);

Answer (score 1):

Actually had nothing to do with the SCSS. We were using the following method to set the correct position for character with the currency mask, and it was firing on both `onChange` and `onBlur`. Preventing it from firing `onBlur` removed this issue.

```
if (!isBlur) setTimeout(() => { inputElement.setSelectionRange(caretPos,
caretPos); },
```